# Cómo redondear a entero en kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Estoy tratando de redondear un número aleatorio como entero

```
var top: Int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) as Int;
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tengo Kotlin 1.2, así que no puedo usar el `Random` de Kotlin

¿Cual es la forma apropiada de obtener ese número entero aleatorio en Kotlin?

Comment: Veo que editaste tu pregunta, usas Kotlin 1.2 :-P

Comment: Yo no... el sitio de codewars :)

Comment: estoy [traduciendo un ejercicio a Kotlin](https://www.codewars.com/kumite/5c1a7005f810a1dc8a000298?sel=5c1a7005f810a1dc8a000298) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el método `Math.floor()` obtiene un valor tipo `double`:

```
public static native double floor(double var);
```

por lo tanto la conversión a Int se realizaría de esta forma:

```
//var top: Int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) as Int;
var top: Int =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 4).toInt();
```

Esto crearía un número aleatorio en el rango de 0 a 3.

---

Usando `kotlin 1.3`

Puedes establecer el limite mediante el método `Random.nextInt(LIMITE`), por ejemplo:

```
val random = Random().nextInt(4);
```

Usando una versión anterior `kotlin 1.3`, por ejemplo 1.2

```
val random  = 
       Random().nextInt((limite + 1) - inicio) +  inicio
```

Comment: favor de aclarar que es el random de Java

Comment: FYI: me refería a que el segundo funciona con Kotlin 1.2, solamente se importa el random de Java y no el de Kotlin

Comment: @RuslanLópez ¿te refieres a import java.util.* ?

Comment: sip, ese Brandom, resulta que el new no es necesario

Answer (score 1):

Para un numero al azar entre 0 y 3 usa:

```
var top: Int=(0..3).shuffled().first()
```

Esta es una forma en la que no necesitas importar el Random de Java.
Usas un IntRange, "revuelves" los elementos en ese conjunto y obtienes unos de esos elementos.
El usar esta forma también te dará opciones como usar step (paso entre los elementos) por ejemplo, para obtener números pares puedes usar:

```
(0..3 step 2).shuffled().first()
```

Comment: has recibido 1 negativo, por que las respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, dale editar y explícala

Comment: o alguien piensa que no es la respuesta correcta mmm.. difícil de saber